# jQuery-ui draggable changes axis after rotation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rotation, jquery-ui-draggable, css-transforms

I've created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BLtT/1/) to demonstrate my problem. Please click **rotate** button a try to move yellow boxes (you can do it before clicking the button).

The problem is obvious - after rotation drag & drop work in a weird way.

I Googled this issue, but found no solution.

The code:

**html**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button id="rotator">rotate</button>

<div id="map">
    <div class="ball">whee</div>
    <div class="ball">heyyy</div>
    <div class="ball">hiii</div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(function() {
    $(".ball").draggable();

    $("#rotator").click(function(){    
        $("#map").css({
            WebkitTransform: 'rotate(120deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(120deg)'
        });
    });
});
```

**css**

```
.ball {width: 100px; height: 100px; background: yellow; border: 1px solid red;}
#map {margin-top: 50px; border: black 1px solid; min-width: 250px; min-height: 250px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the trouble here is that the X and Y axes seem to be oriented to the draggable's parent, which seems odd...

A possible workaround would be to use the `appendTo` and `helper` options like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/wbBtW/1/)**

```
$(function () {
    $(".ball").draggable({
        appendTo: 'body',
        helper: 'clone'
    });

    $("#rotator").click(function () {
        $("#map").css({
            WebkitTransform: 'rotate(120deg)',
                '-moz-transform': 'rotate(120deg)'
        });

        $(".ball").draggable({
            appendTo: 'body',
            helper: 'clone',
            drag: function () {
                $(".ui-draggable-dragging").css({
                    WebkitTransform: 'rotate(120deg)',
                        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(120deg)'
                });
            }
        });

    });
});
```